# Solspace pad_short_weeks and error with simplistic date formatting

Tags: solspace, solspace-calendar, date-format

We're starting our `cal` entry loop like so:

```
{exp:calendar:cal 
  date_range_start="{embed:month_start}-{embed:day_start}-{embed:year_start}"
  date_range_end="{embed:range_end}"
  pad_short_weeks="y"}
```

So for something like `02-05-2014` and `+1 month` what is returned consists of exactly what we need (with a padded start to whatever Sunday happens to be for the given week).

However, when we use `pad_short_weeks="n"` in order to start the day at a specified time that is not whatever the current day is, it only goes until the range end from whatever the actual day is, irrespective of what is specified.

For example:

- today is the `5th`, and if the loops starts as `date_range_start="02-11-2014" date_range_end="+7 days" pad_short_weeks="n"` ends not on the `18th` as it should, but instead it ends on the `12th`, which is 7 days away from today. If it were the `6th` it would end on the `13th`, and so on.
- If we make the `pad_short_weeks="y"` it returns the correct range from the specified date (today, a later date, etc), **however** this has the undesired effect of starting on the beginning of the week instead of the specified date.
- And finally, if the date specified is more than `date_range_end` away, then nothing shows up (if and only if `pad_short_weeks="n"`).

Is this a bug or are we implementing it wrong?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The format for `date_range_start=""` and `date_range_end=""` parameters is **YYYY-MM-DD**, not MM-DD-YYYY.